# Extracting attribute values from a QDomDocument

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qt4

I have an xml block that I need to search through to retrieve a particular attribute's value using QDomDocument. At present that attribute can unfortunately either be in a tag called 'panel' or alternatively 'panel-config'.  To add further complexity often 'panel' can be the root node of the document. Anyway at present my code needs to do this:

```
QDomElement element = XML.documentElement();

if ((element.tagName() == "panel") && (element.hasAttribute(sFACETPANELID))) {
    panelId = element.attribute(sFACETPANELID);
}
else
{
    // Get all our panel nodes
    QDomNodeList nodes = element.elementsByTagName("panel");

    // Loop through our nodes and extract our paned id
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.count(); ++i) {
        QDomElement panel = nodes.at(i).toElement();

        if (panel.hasAttribute(sFACETPANELID)) {
            panelId = panel.attribute(sFACETPANELID);
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Followed by this:

```
QDomNodeList nodes = element.elementsByTagName("panel_config");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.count(); ++i) {
    QDomElement panel_config = nodes.at(i).toElement();

    if (panel_config.hasAttribute(sFACETCLUSTERID)) {
        clusterId = panel_config.attribute(sFACETCLUSTERID);
        break;
    }
}
```

This is pretty horrible. What I ideally require is a way to retrieve a nodeList() for any tags that match either 'panel' or 'panel-config' (elementsByTagNames if you will) and iterate through that list in one single loop. I'd also prefer not to have to check if the top level element is called 'panel' before attempting to get the elementsByTagName. Any suggestions if this can be done in QT?

Comment: Why don't you try QXmlQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: previous code deleted

For lists of elements use

```
//QDomDocument.elementsByTagName(...)
QDomNodeList panelList = XML.elementsByTagName("panel")
QDomNodeList panelCfgList = XML.elementsByTagName("panel-config")
```

it will match the root element too. Unfortunately you can't directly change (or add) nodes in QDomNodeList, so you'll have to make QList that contains both lists and loop through it, or make loop like this

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < panelList.count() || i < panelCfgList.count(); i++)
    {
        if (i < panelList.count())
        {
            QDomElement panel = panelList.at(i).toElement();
            if (panel.hasAttribute(sFACETPANELID))
            {
                panelId = panel.attribute(sFACETPANELID);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i < panelCfgList.count())
        {
            QDomElement panelCfg = panelCfgList.at(i).toElement();
            if (panelCfg.hasAttribute(sFACETPANELID))
            {
                panelCfgId = panelCfg.attribute(sFACETPANELID);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rift. The loop above iterates through all elements whilst I'm ideally looking for something to just loop through the named elements above.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to come up with different solution.

Comment: I've made a little edit (old solution was deleted), how about now?